# Woocommerce update_checkout trigger

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I made a checkout page with a select field, when i change the select, i call

```
update_checkout
```

so that i can add some custom fee based on the select value

also the list of options is (or should be based) on shipping method, this is driving me to a loop that i can exit.

I change the select, the checkout is correctly updated with the additional fee, but when i change the shipping method, the update_checkout is triggered and it recalculate the list of options (and this is correct), but at the moment the select is filled with the new values, the update_checkout is triggered again. And this way the update_checkout recalucalte agai refilling the select (and setting it back to default value)

its quiete hard to explain what is happening, but im looking for a way to intercept what is calling update_checkout.

Comment: My idea is an ugly solution but you can try. You can write javascript code that will disable the shipping options so that they can not be modified after your custom select has `changed` (an option is selected)

Comment: thank you for your reply, unluckly i can't approach this way (i was already thinking it), because the option sould be always available and constantly changing, im trying with a hidden field that "dictate" he fact the select had a previous value

Comment: maybe you can assign that value to the cart object and persist that way

Comment: Solved with a hidden filed (ugly solution), setting the value of the hidden field on select change, the on the 'updated_checkout' i grab the value from the hidden field and if is still present in the select i force the selection.
it's not perfect, since there are some "flashes" on the select field that may confuse the user

Comment: I'm glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a hidden filed (ugly solution), setting the value of the hidden field on select change, the on the 'updated_checkout' i grab the value from the hidden field and if is still present in the select i force the selection. it's not perfect, since there are some "flashes" on the select field that may confuse the user